# FOSS version of SQLCompare or something similar?

Tags: sql-server, schema, sqlcompare

Actually, free is good enough, it doesn't have to be open source :)

I'm currently using the Schema Compare utility of VS2008, but it doesn't have a command line interface and has some other weaknesses as well.

I'm wondering what free tools others are using to provide command line schema comparisons/synchronizations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago I compared a bunch of comparison tools including [Starinix](http://www.starinix.com/sqlcompare01.htm) and [OpenDBiff](http://www.codeplex.com/OpenDBiff/).

Overall I was dissapointed, SqlDelta and SqlCompare are in a league of their own.

Comment: For the price SQLDelta is very hard to beat.  Last I checked they were about a third the price of other tools with comparable features.

Answer (score 0):

We may suggest our own tool - [dbForge Schema Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/), but it's a 30-days trial shareware. But anyway, you can get a free license, just visit our [free license conditions page](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/get-free-license.html).